# Does a foreign key need to appear in children of children?

Tags: foreign-keys, primary-key, parent-child, children

I have a set of tables with children of children, like so:

Clients (PK ClientID) which is parent (one to many) to

Property (PK PropertyID, FK ClientID) which is parent (one to many) to

Property Detail (PK PropDetailID, FK PropertyID) and Case (PK CaseID, FK PropertyID).

Should the foreign keys for the parent tables be repeated further down? That is, should my tables look like this:

Clients (PK ClientID)

Property (PK PropertyID, FK Client ID)

PropertyDetail (PK PropDetailID, FK PropertyID, FK Client ID)

Case (PK CaseID, FK PropertyID, FK ClientID)

instead? And if neither setup is normalized, what's the normalized way to do this?

Comment: Thank you! I'd upvote all of you but if I were allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the foreign keys should not be repeated because you can access this information with a simple join. Adding it to the grandchildren adds redundancy which can give problems when the two get out of sync. Your first design looks better than your second.

Depending on the meaning of the word `property` it could be that you are using an [entity attribute value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) (EAV) model to store client properties. There are some situations where an EAV model is appropriate but in general you should try to avoid it. If possible try to use a fixed schema instead.

Further reading:

- [EAV FAIL](http://karwin.blogspot.com/2009/05/eav-fail.html)

Comment: `Property` includes property address and some additional unique information (like purchase date). The `PropertyDetail` table may be an EAV model - it's based on an external key, a property ID number assigned by the county. A `Property` may contain 0 to 600 of these county ID numbers, so `PropertyDetail` joins them to `Property` but avoids null values in the main `Property` table. Maybe this is the wrong approach? (Also - the county ID is unique, but 16 digits seemed like it would be murder on indexing.)

Comment: @user450957: If you have a huge number of properties and most of them are usually NULL then this is one of the occasions where EAV can be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have both Foreign keys for PropertyDetail/ Case. These ones can be navigated to.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to have the foreign keys repeated further down -- you can determine a property detail's ClientID by looking at the Property's ClientID.

All the information you need can be determined by simple joins.